# JQuery ul li click move to next in list

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, navigation

OK, nearly there, looking to use Jquery and css class (images) to navigate up and down an HTML ul li list in the same way a select option drop down works only want to only display 1 item, not a drop down button, but a next/prev css class to work though the list with only one item showing at a time so the whole effect is a bit like a spinner. e.g.

```
$('.next').click (function( MOVE TO NEXT ITEM IN LIST ))
$('.prev').click (function( MOVE TO PREV ITEM IN LIST ))
```

with a list a bit like

```
<ul class="">
<li> Item 1</li>
<li> Item 2</li>
<li> Item 3</li>
<li> etc ....
</ul>
<img src="but..." class="next">
<img src="but..." class="prev">
```

Suggestions please - and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var active = 0; // starts at zero
var list = $('ul');

$('.next').bind('click', function() {
    active = active == list.length-1 ? 0 : active + 1;
});

$('.prev').bind('click', function() {
    active = active == 0 ? list.length-1 ? active - 1;
});

var getActive = function() {
    return list.children('li').eq(active);
};
```

Now, use `getActive()` to get the active list element.

**UPDATE**: if you want to hide all items except the active list item, just add:

```
$('.prev,.next').bind('click', function() {
    getActive().show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

People need to check their code before posting it! Neither of the above answers work.

I fixt it:

```
 var active = 0; // starts at zero
 var list = $('ul');

 list.children('li').eq('0').siblings().hide(); // Hide all except first list element

 $('.next').bind('click', function() {
  active = active == list.children('li').length-1 ? 0 : active + 1;
 });

 $('.prev').bind('click', function() {
  active = active == 0 ? list.children('li').length-1 : active - 1;
 });


 var getActive = function() {
  return list.children('li').eq(active);
 };

 $('.prev,.next').bind('click', function() {
  getActive().show().siblings().hide();
 });
```

Comment: this is the best answer.tnkx @Moridine

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you only want 1 list element at a time to be visible. To do this I would modify the functions from David's answer to do something like this.

```
var active = 0; // starts at zero
var list = $('ul');

var hideListItems = function(active) {
    $.each(list, function(count, item) {
        if (count !== active) {
            item.css({'display': 'none'});
        } else {
            item.css({'display': 'block'});
        }
    }
};

$('.next').bind('click', function() {
    active = active == list.length-1 ? 0 : active + 1;
    hideListItems(active);
});

$('.prev').bind('click', function() {
    active = active == 0 ? list.length-1 ? active - 1;
    hideListItems(active);
});
```